# What does this message in paper say?

Tags: cipher, mystery, symbols, paper-folding

You wake up in an old horse wagon and get a piece of paper with strange symbols. What does it say?
//Anyone can help me. Please!
[image]

Comment: "*Anyone can help me. Please!*" shows that it is not your own puzzle. Could you provide the source of it ?

Comment: I've got this strange puzzle with no hints in my training test for CTF contest

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Ongoing contests aren't allowed to be answered here at puzzling, as it ruins the contest.